# uTorrent - download all *new* items in an rss feed?

Tags: windows-7, rss, utorrent

In uTorrent, you can specify `"Do not download automatically"` or `"Download all automatically"`.

The problem with the latter option is that it immediately tries to download **all** items in the feed, and I see no way to *not* download every entry in the feed.

How do I set up a subscription to just download all new entries in an RSS feed? If uTorrent can't do this, can some other torrent client?

Comment: You might want to use an intermediary to get the new items, and then generate an RSS feed from that. You can then feed that to utorrent.

Comment: FWIW, I just ask it to download all and then remove all the torrents it just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to "Download all automatically" stop the torrents that start, then when new torrents are added to the feed they will download automatically.

If you want the file to download to a location, set the location in the RSS downloader before you tick the "Download all automatically" box.

When you remove the torrents, make sure you use "Remove all data + .torrent"

Comment: When I do this and press "update feed", all the old torrents restart.

Comment: Do they display as "previously Downloaded"? Try "Delete Torrent and Data" rather than just stopping the Torrent.

Comment: That did it. Delete Torrent and Data was key to making this work.

Comment: Excellent, cheers for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with that when tried using it too. so what I did was leave the Utorrent RSS Feed alone, and used Google Desktop bar RSS feed to get the news, then get the torrent that way. Not too bad IMO. Of course you can choose anything you wish and does not have to be Google Desktop widgets. You won't be restricted from new releases of other things either this way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

1. Options->RSS Downloader
2. Select the Favorite (or create if required)
3. Check Episode Number
4. Set the filter to be the appropriate episodes
5. Click Close

For example if I've already seen Series 1 Episode 16, I would set the Episode Number to 1x17- the dash at the end means episode 17 and those after it.